# PyDev can't write cache file

Tags: pydev

How do I handle the message that appears when I start a PyDev Jython run?

*sys-package-mgr*: can't write cache file....

I don't know what would make writing a cache file possible. I don't even know what a cache file is.

Answer (score 1):

In PyDev, if you go to:

`Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > Jython Interpreter`

You can see that there's a `-Dpython.cachedir` entry (with a `Browse` button right next to it).

If you set it to a folder, PyDev will set the Jython cachedir to be used to the place you specify (that's a helper directory for Jython to cache internal stuff).

Comment: Thank you, Fabio. Unfortunately, that had no effect. But adding-Dpython.cachedir=<my directory> to VM arguments in the launch configuration did.